# Remove p-values for groups with a mean lower than specified value

Tags: r, ggplot2, p-value, ggpubr

I was wondering if there was a way to specify which p-values get shown on a ggboxplot from the ggpubr package in R but I have been unsuccessfull in trying to do so.

The only option I have found is to filter the data beforehand but I do not want to exclude those groups when I make my graph. i.e. I want to only show p-values for groups with a mean > my reference group but I still want to see all of the data.

In my example here I would like for the "lo" group to hide its level of significance while still remaining on the graph since its mean is lower than the reference group

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(dplyr)

Plant<-c("ref","ref","ref","ref","ref","ref","ref","ref","ref",
         "hi","hi","hi","hi","hi","hi","hi","hi","hi",
         "lo","lo","lo","lo","lo","lo","lo","lo","lo")
Delta.CCI<-c(11.05,11.45,9.65,10.65,10.15,8.95,8.95,12.45,8.95,
             20.56,20.66,19.76,20.36,20.26,20.06,19.16,19.16,19.06,
             2.18,1.58,2.98,1.11,1.91,0.21,1.68,2.11,0.51)
df<-data.frame(Plant,Delta.CCI)

#generate a list of comparisons for the data frame
cdf<-compare_means(Delta.CCI ~ Plant, 
                   data = df, 
                   ref.group = "ref")
#make a new list
my_list <- vector()
#for every other comparison put a 1 in the list
#this is so I can stagger the p-values later since there are so many in my actual data set
for(i in 1:nrow(cdf)+1){
  if(i %% 2 == 0){
    my_list[i] <- 1
  } else {
    my_list[i] <- 0
  }
}

#Make the box plot
p<-ggboxplot(df,
             title = "A",
             x="Plant",
             y="Delta.CCI")+
  #rotate the text so it is legible
  rotate_x_text(angle = 90)+
  #make a line showing where the mean of the LBA/GFP group is
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(df$Delta.CCI[df$Plant=="ref"]), linetype = 2)+
  #add out p-values to the plot as significance labels
  stat_compare_means(label="p.signif",label.y=my_list+28,ref.group="ref")
p
```

Comment: I do not understand your loop-approach. Does not look data-dependent. Also notice that `1:2+1` is different from `1:(2+1)`

Comment: my loop-approach is not data dependent I have over 200 groups in my data set that I am trying to visualize and it is impossible to read the significance labels unless I stagger them. It is less relevant for the example I gave here but I did not want to alter my code too much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use `stat_pvalue_manual`. To this end I use the lower level functions from the `rstatix` package to create the data.frame of test statistics. To this df you could easily add the y positions without the need of a creating a separate vector. Additonally, via the argument `detailed=TRUE` `wilcox_test` allows to add an estimate of the difference in means to conditionally replace unwanted labels with an empty string:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(rstatix)

cdf <- df |>
  wilcox_test(Delta.CCI ~ Plant, ref.group = "ref",
              detailed = TRUE) |>
  add_significance("p") |>
  mutate(
    y.position = 28 + (row_number() %% 2 == 0),
    p.signif = if_else(estimate < 0, p.signif, "")
  )

p <- ggboxplot(df,
  title = "A",
  x = "Plant",
  y = "Delta.CCI"
) +
  rotate_x_text(angle = 90) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(df$Delta.CCI[df$Plant == "ref"]), linetype = 2) +
  stat_pvalue_manual(
    cdf,
    label = "p.signif",
    x = "group2"
  )
p
```

[image]